# Batch upload of Blobs to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, scripting, file-upload

I'm currently migrating a site to Google App Engine. Previously, all the images and static resources (100s of MBs of the stuff) was just part of the deployment.

Now, it's clear, I should use Blob Storage for this in GAE (otherwise updating the app will be mega-painful!).

I need to batch upload these images from my disk to GAE and suspect I need some kind of script to do this. Any ideas or suggestions of the best approach?

Comment: You might want to consider putting these static assets in Amazon S3, since if you upload them to blobstore you'll need a way to convert their friendly name ("images/logo.png") to their blobstore key before serving them.  This will add more complexity and bloat to your project, and possibly make it harder to maintain.

Comment: Actually, its pretty easy to serve files by their friendly name in GAE. See my other question on the subject for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671901/referencing-blobs-in-gae-the-smart-way

Comment: I should note - I don't know how expensive in terms of CPU at BlobStore this work is (selecting by filename, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current bulkloader doesn't support this, but it's possible to write one yourself. The process goes something like this:

1. Write a handler that handles uploaded blobs, described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob). Have it write the key of the newly created blob to the datastore, or return it via a redirect to the uploader, or whatever is most suitable for your app.
2. Write an upload script. You can use [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) to call the blobstore `create_upload_url` function, then use urllib to upload the file. Be sure to encode the file in a multipart form for the blobstore to recognize it correctly.

As a side note, uploading an app uploads only the modified files, so you can store large amounts of static content, and they'll only be uploaded if they've changed. This probably doesn't help you here, though, as apps are limited to 300mb in size.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a play with these and mark answered when I get it working. BTW The other reason uploading as an app wouldn't work is because the app allows dynamic uploads after deployment. BlobStore is the clear choice for this. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm almost there thanks to your help. Have this all running and am using MultipartPostHandler (http://pipe.scs.fsu.edu/PostHandler/MultipartPostHandler.py) to help me upload the file with urllib2. However, I get a 500 error and no information to help... thoughts?

   url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/files')
   opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
   params = { "file" : open(".. path to file ..", "rb")
   opener.open(url, params)

...

   HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: 

No details? No help, no idea!? :(

Comment: @ConfusedNoob By default, App Engine shows a standard 500 page for uncaught exceptions, because your users don't need to see the stacktrace (and it can be a security risk). Check your app's Admin Console, under the logs section, to see the stacktrace.

Comment: You legend. I'm actually using the dev server - it didn't occur to me to look at the dev servers log file (muppet). Quickly got to the bottom of the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

It's easier than that. There is a freeware app that lets you drag and drop files into your cloud storage. Check out [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/)

Comment: This is irrelevant, since it doesn't upload to the App Engine blobstore.

Comment: shame, would have been perfect :/